# Java - array types to Object type cast

Tags: java, arrays, types

How does java convert array types to Object types ?
For example, say we have an int array 'src' and we use System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length) then how does java convert a primitive type array to an instance of Object ? Also while copying to 'dest', how does it know how to copy it without knowing the type ?

Does it just do a byte by byte copy like a clone, because when i run the following code

```
int[][] a = new int[][] {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,0}};
int[][] b = new int[a.length][a[0].length];
System.arraycopy(a,0,b,0,a.length);
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a));
b[1][3]=100;
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a[0]));
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a[1]));
```

I get the following output

```
[[I@7d08c1b7, [I@49e61582]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 100, 0]
```

What is the output `[[I@7d08c1b7, [I@49e61582]` ? Is it like the address of the array a[0] and a[1] (like array of pointers in C/C++) ?

Also how does a[1][3] change if i changed b[1][3] and what is the correct way to make a copy of a ?

EDIT: Also how does `java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(Object array)` work ?

EDIT: I want to point out that I change the value of **b**[1][3] but while printing **a**[1], the value **a**[1][3] is also changing. Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does java convert array types to Object types ?

Array types are already a sub-class of Object, so there's no need for any conversion.

> how does java convert a primitive type array to an instance of Object ? Also while copying to 'dest', how does it know how to copy it without knowing the type ?

A primitive type array is already an instance of Object, so no conversion is required. The JVM knows at runtime the types of elements stored in the source and target arrays. If they don't match, `ArrayStoreException` is thrown.

> how does a[1][3] change if i changed b[1][3] and what is the correct way to make a copy of a ?

`System.arraycopy` doesn't do deep copy. It copies the primitive or reference in each position of the source array to the target array. When an element of the source array is itself a reference to a sub-array, the reference is copied to the target array as is. Therefore `a[1] == b[1]` (they refer to the same array object), so changing `b[1][3]` changes `a[1][3]`.

If you want each sub-array to be a copy of the original sub-array, you have to execute `System.arraycopy` for each sub-array separately after executing `System.arraycopy` for the main array.

Answer (score 1):

> How does java convert array types to Object types ?

An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. It lives on the heap.

> What is the output "[[I@7d08c1b7, [I@49e61582]" ? Is it like the
>   address of the array a[0] and a[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)) (like array of pointers in C/C++) ?

"[[I@7d08c1b7, [I@49e61582]" are the class names & hashcodes for a[0] & a[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int))

> Also how does a[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int))[3] change if i changed b[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int))[3] and what is the
>   correct way to make a copy of a ?

I wrote a sample code

```
        int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        int[] b = new int[a.length];

        b=Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
        //System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);
        b[2]=789;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 789, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Change in b won't affect values of a.

If you want to change b & also want a subsequent change in a

just do

```
b=a;  //now b is a shallow copy of a
```

Well the standard way of copying an array object is to use [Arrays.copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)) method.

Comment: Your sample code copies a one dimensional array, so it doesn't behave the same as the 2D array in the question.

Answer (score 0):

From [Object javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> ```
>  `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the output "[[I@7d08c1b7, [I@49e61582]" ? Is it like the
>   address of the array a[0] and a[1] (like array of pointers in C/C++) ?

It's class name and hashCode.
    `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

> Also how does a[1][3] change if i changed b[1][3] and what is the
>   correct way to make a copy of a ?

System.arraycopy will create a new array, so what changed to b, there's no impact to b.

> EDIT: Also how does java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(Object array)
>   work ?

If anArray is statically typed to an array type, you should use anArray.length (not a method call). You'd use the reflection form if you only had a reference to the array as Object.

Comment: `System.arraycopy will create a new array, so what changed to b, there's no impact to b.` I'm assuming you meant `System.arraycopy will create a new array, so what changed to b, there's no impact to a.`. This is still wrong, since `arraycopy` performs a shallow copy, so even though `a!=b`, `a[i]==b[i]` is true, and changing b[i][j] will change a[i][j].